# lodown not downloading the micro dataset

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to download AHS microdata using Anthony Damico's lodown package.
However, when I just hit the following command, it does not work

```
ahs_cat <-
  get_catalog( "ahs", file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "AHS" ) )
```

Main directory and sub-directory doesn't have problem, and I tried to change it several times and I got the following error in more than 50 lines.

```
trying URL 'https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/ahs/data/1973/ahs- national-puf-microdata.html'
Content type 'text/html' length unknown
downloaded 252 KB

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

When I type warnings(), the following warnings (5o times this message) appear.

```
50: In readLines(tf) :
  incomplete final line found on 
'C:\Users\abdf\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAZ3lgV\file90f83e444932'
```

Comment: hi, `get_catalog` only grabs what's available.  to download the datasets, you'd need to use the `lodown()` function in one of the two ways documented on the ahs page?

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Hi- I think I totally misunderstood that part. I thought get_catalog -> subset -> lodown sequece enables me to bypass downloading the whole survey data. From your answer, there seems to be no other way but to download in full first, is this a right understanding?

Comment: the example at http://asdfree.com/american-housing-survey-ahs.html#simplified-download-and-importation-3 shows how to download 2013 only